# JavaFX Docking Systems -- how to make undraggable node with desired behavior

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying out both `DockFX` (https://github.com/RobertBColton/DockFX) and `AnchorFX` (https://github.com/alexbodogit) (using Clojure as the host language, in Win7 x64)

The nice thing about DockFX is that you can drag from the tabs, and set the title bar to NULL to make the pane non-draggable, but the `DockingPane` still allows siblings next to (which is ok), or on top of (which is not okay) the non-draggable `DockNode`, leaving a skinny little section of tab representing the non-draggable node when another pane is dragged on top, as shown here.  This is what it looks like when a non-draggable `TableView` gets a `TreeView` dragged on top.

[image: The skinny tab represents a non-draggable node underneath the <code>TreeView</code> node]

Question for `DockFX`:

- How to prevent things from being dragged on top of a non-draggable `DockNode`, so I don't see a skinny vestigial tab?

For AnchorFX, I like how you can create substations, etc., and it feels a little snappier (actually about 1/10th the time to create a `Station` compared to `DockFX`).  I modified the code so a null title removes the title bar and makes the node non-draggable.

Questions for `AnchorFX`:

1. How to prevent things from being dropped on top? (next to is okay).
2. How to eliminate title bar when a node is tabbed on top of other nodes?
3. How to drag from tab instead of title bar?

Answer (score 0):

1. I modified the DockFX code so the popup does not appear if the DockTitleBar is null.
2. Inherently fixed by above.
3. Already works with DockFX, haven't tried fixing this with AnchorFX.